# count and group by to get totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT 
   *, COUNT(examID) AS ExamCount 
FROM 
   ExamSession
GROUP BY
   [examID], [userID], [sessionID]
```

This gives me a result set, but the `ExamCount` has a '1' in each row even if an exam is displayed in more than 1 row... I'm trying to get the number of times an `examID` appears in the result set.

SO the result set looks like this:

```
examID | userID | sessionID | ExamCount
---------------------------------------------------------
1111   | xxxxxx | xxxxxx    |   1
1111   | xxxxxx | xxxxxx    |   1
1111   | xxxxxx | xxxxxx    |   1
2222   | xxxxxx | xxxxxx    |   1
2222   | xxxxxx | xxxxxx    |   1
3333   | xxxxxx | xxxxxx    |   1
3333   | xxxxxx | xxxxxx    |   1
3333   | xxxxxx | xxxxxx    |   1
3333   | xxxxxx | xxxxxx    |   1
```

How can I get a count of the number of times an `examID` appears?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Code:

```
COUNT(examID) OVER(PARTITION BY examID) AS ExamCount
```

Comment: Could you explain this? Thanks

Comment: @Horaciux [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) explains the `OVER` clause in SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a bit on jbarker answer

```
if object_id(N'dbo.groupTry',N'U') is not null
    drop table dbo.groupTry
create table dbo.groupTry
(
    examID int,
    userID int,
    sessionID int,
    ExamCount int
)

insert into dbo.groupTry values
(1111, 1234, 4321, 1),
(1111, 9876, 6789, 1),
(1111, 8765, 5678, 1),
(2222, 7654, 4567, 1),
(2222, 6543, 3456, 1),
(3333, 5432, 2345, 1),
(3333, 1987, 1789, 1),
(3333, 1876, 1678, 1),
(3333, 1765, 1567, 1)

select 
    count(g.examID) over(partition by examID) as ExamCount, 
    g.examID,
    g.userID,
    g.sessionID,
    g.ExamCount 
from dbo.groupTry g
group by examID,
    userID,
    sessionID,
    ExamCount
```

In my own simple words, over just means: don't look at all the columns when you count, just look and count the unique rows of examID (because we are partitioning by examID).

Comment: @Horaciux no problem. Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT examId, COUNT(examID) AS ExamCount 
   FROM ExamSession
   GROUP BY [examID]
```

EDIT:
If you need all columns

```
select t1.*, t2.ExamCount 
from(
    SELECT *       
    FROM 
       ExamSession 
    GROUP BY
       [examID], [userID], [sessionID]) t1 
inner join (
    SELECT examId, COUNT(examID) AS ExamCount 
       FROM ExamSession
       GROUP BY [examID]) t2
 on t1.examID=t2.examID
```

Comment: This only works without the other columns that he specified in his output that he wanted.

Comment: NP.  The more answers the merrier!

Answer (score 0):

edit:

```
select A.examid, B.UserId, b.SessionID, A.ExamCount from 
( SELECT examId, COUNT(examID) AS ExamCount 
   FROM ExamSession
   GROUP BY [examID]) A
JOIN (select [examID] ,[userID]  ,[sessionID] from ExamSession) B
on a.examid = b.examid
```

Comment: Oops, my bad. It should be B.SessionID. Edited my answer.